Trying to redirect api calls to backend with Caddy reverse proxy but getting error 405
I have a backend (spring) and frontend (react) deployed in an EC2 instance, backend is running on port 8080. The frontend uses axios with a baseUrl:
baseURL: "https://website.com/"
The idea is to redirect requests like "https://website.com/api/something" to the backend instead and I was trying to do it with caddy with this configuration:
www.website.com {
        redir https://website.com{uri} # Ensure the `www` subdomain redirects to the root domain
}


website.com {
        root * /var/www/html # Path to your React app's build folder

        # Serve static files (React app)
        file_server

        # Redirect all routes not matching files to index.html for client-side routing
        try_files {path} /index.html 

        reverse_proxy /api/* localhost:8080 # Proxy requests to backend API
}

When I directly call the backend with <ec2InstanceIp>:8080 in Postman I get a correct answer but when I try through the website I get
 405 (Method Not Allowed)
I noticed in testing that the backend only responds positively when using http and does not work with https, while my website is using https.
What could be wrong here?

The issue is that try files is being executed always so all the requests no matter the path used end up returning index.html. To fix it I followed a suggestion from Matt Holt in this forum. By using router and switching the reverse proxy to be the first line, the backend starts being called before.
# Main site for biospringbok.com
biospringbok.com {
        root * /var/www/html # Path to your React app's build folder


        #Route is used to ensure that first reverse proxy is executed and only resort to try files if its not an api call
        route {
                reverse_proxy /api/* localhost:8080

                # Redirect all routes not matching files to index.html for client-side routing
                try_files {path} /index.html # This allows React Router to take over for non-file URLs

                # Serve static files (React app)
                file_server
           }
}

